# Forming Xpath Query for total Google results

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I've used this formula in Google Spreadsheets in the past to input the number of search results into a cell. The formula's not working anymore and I know I need to fix the xpath query.

any ideas?

Current formula:

```
=importXML("http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q="&A2,"//p[@id='resultStats']/b[3]")
```

Spreadsheet for public testing:

https://spreadsheets8.google.com/ccc?key=tJzmFllp7Sk1lt23cXSVXFw&authkey=CM625OUO#gid=0

Comment: @user619879: Are you looking for the XPath expression that selects the URLs or the text from a Google's search result?

Comment: I'm looking for the number of search results (e.g. 1,200,000,000) in the case of the query 'China'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use IMPORTXML to get URL of first result of Google Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730811/how-to-use-importxml-to-get-url-of-first-result-of-google-search)

Answer (score 0):

> `=ImportXML(A2,"//*[@id='resultStats']")`

It doesn't produce the number only, but it's a start

Answer (score 0):

Set C2 `=ImportXML(A2,"//*[@id='resultStats']")`
Then use `=REGEXREPLACE(C2 ;"^About(.*) results";"$1")`

Answer (score 0):

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def google_results(query):

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'
}



html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', id='resultStats')

return int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', div.text.split()[1])))
```

print(google_results('test'))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).