# How to use google docs to grab google search results?

Tags: google-docs

I want to use google docs to grab google search results
My formula is:

> =ImportXML(URL,"//div[@id='resultStats']")

Google docs always returns #N/A, is there something wrong with the formula?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Are you using Google docs API or scraping from HTML link? Post link.

Comment: Also, is it a spreadsheet or document or something else?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. I'd like to do the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018110/forming-xpath-query-for-total-google-results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use IMPORTXML to get URL of first result of Google Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730811/how-to-use-importxml-to-get-url-of-first-result-of-google-search)