# How to use IMPORTXML to get URL of first result of Google Search?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to use the ImportXML function in Google Spreadsheets to find the URL of the first result of a Google Search (not including any links to advertised links). I thought I understood that all search results are displayed in an h3 element with class "r", and I hoped the XPath expression below would find a) all links to search results (the part in brackets) and then b) select the first one of those:

```
=importxml(A1,"(//h3[@class='r']/a/@href)[1]")
```

[where A1 is e.g. "="https://www.google.com/search?q=U+Chicago&num=10""]

Unfortunately I do get links to Google Maps.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of filtering through the results, you should set google parameters to only return one result. The query parameters should include the number(num) of responses and the page (start)

```
"https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow&num=1&start=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

narrow down your query by relevant id, like:

```
//ol[@id='rso']//h3[@class='r']/a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same thing. Haven't found a way to get a unique XPath query that only returns one URL, but you can force Google to return only the top search result!

In your search URL, change "&num=10" to "&num=1". That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both, you can have it return one result with "&num=1" and also use the xpath "//cite"